# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute_list'

Tags: python, requests

написал такой код.
Библиотеки подключены

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS= {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
    }

s = requests.Session()
s.get("https://www.heroeswm.ru")
data = {'LOGIN_redirect': '1', 'login': login, 'pass': password, 'pliv': 15248}

r = s.post("https://www.heroeswm.ru/login.php", data=data, headers=HEADERS)
r.encoding = 'windows-1251'

url = 'https://www.heroeswm.ru/object-info.php?id=346'
our_data = {'code':'s98csh'}
hiden_key = 'id' #Нужно достать значение к этому ключу
hiden_key2 = 'id2'
hiden_key3 = 'idr'
hiden_key4 = 'num'
hiden_key5 = 'id3'

ses = requests.Session()
s_response = s.post(url, data = our_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s_response.content, 'html.parser')
hiden_value = soup.find('input', {'id' : hiden_key,'id2' : hiden_key2,'idr' : hiden_key3,'num' : 
iden_key4,'id3' : hiden_key5}).get_attribute_list('value')

our_data[hiden_key] = hiden_value
s_response = ses.post(url, data = our_data)
```

После запуска кода мне выдает ошибку

```
File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/HeroesWMBot-master/bot.py", line 27, in <module>
hiden_value = soup.find('input', {'id' : hiden_key,'id2' : hiden_key2,'idr' : hiden_key3,'num' : 
hiden_key4,'id3' : hiden_key5}).get_attribute_list('value')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_attribute_list'
```

Когда я спарсил эту страницу, то эти данные там присутствуют
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он их не может найти? И как исправить эту ошибку.

Comment: Объект soup.find() не имеет атрибута 'get_attribute_list'. Написано, правда, на английском. 
Почитайте насчет BeautifulSoup более подробно и все получится.

Comment: Почитал офф документацию, они просто в примерах вытягивают через класс и атрибут, но у меня так не работает, он просто возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: Элементарно написал строчку, (soup.find(name='id')) , он выдает пустой список, в дебаге проверял страница парсится и присутствуют эти значения, вообще не понимаю, что не так

Comment: Ну то есть в s_response.content эти данные есть? Что значит "в дебаге проверял"?

Comment: К сожалению, без логина и пароля проверить ничего не получается.

Comment: Да, в s_resoponse.content эти данные есть, ну в отладке смотрел. Логин-CheKavo123, пароль-v5ro848e, для теста создал, буду благодарен если поможете